# Не распознаётся текст с пробелом

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Делаю приложение на Kotlin под Android и столкнулась с проблемой. Суть приложения - сканировать текст и находить вредные "Е"шки в отсканированном тексте. Когда я сканирую текст в виде: "Е123", то никаких проблем не возникает совсем. Но, если в тексте имеется пробел:"Е 123", то никаким образом не получается увидеть эту "ешку" как вредную и вывести ее на экран списком с остальными найденными вредными веществами.

Функция:

```
private fun processImage() {

    if(imageBitmap!=null){

        val image = imageBitmap?.let {
            InputImage.fromBitmap(it, 0)
        }

        image?.let { image ->
            recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                    if (result.text.isBlank()) {
                        binding.textView.text = "Текст не найден."
                    } else {
                        val recognizedWords = result.text.split("\\s+".toRegex()).map { word -> word.replace(",", "") }
                        val dangerWords = listOf("E121", "E 121", "E123", " E 123", " E 123 ", "E 123 ","E 123", "E128", "E 128", "E216", "E 216", "E217", "E 217", "E240", "E 240", "E294a", "E 294a", "E294 a", "E 294 a", "E294b", "E 294b", "E294 b", "E 294 b", "Hydroxyzine")
                        val foundDangerWords = recognizedWords.filter { word -> dangerWords.any { dangerWord -> word.trim().replace(" ", "").equals(dangerWord.replace(" ", ""), ignoreCase = true) } }
                        if (foundDangerWords.isNotEmpty()) {
                            binding.textView.text = "Найдены запрещенные вещества: \n" + foundDangerWords.joinToString("\n")
                        } else {
                            binding.textView.text = "Не найдены запрещенные вещества."
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please, select image first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Текст без пробелов нормально сканирует и выводит вредное:
[image: все норм]

Но если есть пробелы:

[image: все плоха(]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли вообще с этим что либо сделать? Уже совсем нет сил, ничего не понимаю

Comment: Зачем вам в списке "слова" с пробелвми, если вы пробелы перед сравнением все равно удаляете?

Comment: Оффтоп, несколько лет назад по телевизору наткнулся на передачу про "вредные е-шки", и там рассказывалось, что "вот E330 самая вредная" (без объяснения, что это за вещество). Ну да, лимонная кислота наверное вредна в больших дозировках (как и любое вещество), но я бы не сказал что она в целом особо вредна. А так-то конечно и [дигидрогена монооксид](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4) каждый год убивает тысячи людей.

Comment: @insolor аххахахах, да, по телику чего только не несут в массы, а люди верят. Но мне хватило ума зайти на сайт роспотребнадзора за вредными "Е" для массива, а "Hydroxyzine" рандомно со своих таблеток закинула в массив, чисто потестить)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так происходит, потому что вы сначала разделаете слова пробелами, и слово `E 123` разделается на два слова `E` и `123`.

Попробуйте сначала разделять слова запятыми, а потом удалять пробелы.

Вот пример.

```java
    public static List<String> findHazardousSubstances(String hs) {
        var dangerWords = List.of("E121", "E123", "E128", "E216", "E217", "E240", "E294a", "E294b", "Hydroxyzine");

        List<String> hazardWordsFormattedList =
                // сначала разделяем слова запятыми
                Arrays.stream(hs.split(","))
                        // потом удаляем пробелы
                        .map(word -> word.replaceAll("\\s+", ""))
                        // на всякий случай если будут дубликаты
                        .distinct()
                        // проверяем есть ли в списке вредных веществ
                        .filter(word -> dangerWords.contains(word))
                        .toList();
        
        return hazardWordsFormattedList;
    }
```

Comment: Блин. Спасибо Вам огромное, правда. На неспавшую голову тяжело было нормально алгоритм придумать, Вы очень выручили.  = * Лучи добра любви * =

Comment: Спасибо. Рад был помочь)